# In DNN, How to combine my .js file or JS Code also with newly created Page

Tags: javascript, html, dotnetnuke

How to add this javascript with my newly created page in DNN?

I tried many ways to add javascript and Jquery but no reflection i found

```
var CheckedArray = [];

function addPackageDataToList(packageId) {
    if (packageId == '1') {
        var qty = $('#txtPackageQuantity' + packageId).val();
        if (qty != '' && qty != undefined && qty > 0) {
            var obj = {
                PackageName: "Package 1",
                Qty: $('#txtPackageQuantity' + packageId).val(),
                Price: 50
            } 
        } else {
            alert("Please add valid quantity");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try put it on Module Settings > Header or Footer.

Comment: I agree with @erw13n put your page in edit mode, click the gear icon for a html module, then advanced settings, you will see a header /footer text box for the module.  You could also just switch to basic textbox and put it there if that is the only content for this module.

Comment: Thanks @erw13n it's working for me.
but i want to redirect page from one domain to another using js it's not redirecting and also redirect me to same page

Comment: please create another question for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add this to a single page, one way to do this is to add it to an HTML module.

Add the module to the page.
Edit and go to HTML mode.
Wrap your code in script tags.
Save the module.

Before doing this you will want to make sure that the HTML Editor is NOT configured to strip code from the module.  You do this on the Host, HTML Editor Manager page (DNN 8 and below) or  Site Settings -> Site Behavior -> More -> Open HTML Manager in DNN 9.x.

Comment: Thanks Joe,
please provide me step for  

DNN Version: 08.00.04 (226)

Comment: put it on Module Settings > Header or Footer. @erw13n  it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the editor's settings, go to Host, HTML Editor Manager.

If you are using the DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider, you will find some checkboxes that should be unchecked, especially "Remove Scripts."

If you are using the CKEditor, you may not have to do anything.

So ... stick in a script and see if it gets erased.  If it does, changed the Editor configuration options.